# No marketplace entries found to handle Execution compile-protoc

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, m2eclipse

I am trying to import Hadoop source code into Eclipse (again) but while importing I am getting following error :

> **"No marketplace entries found to handle Execution compile-protoc"**

Following is the screenshot of the error :

[image]

I am following steps given in "Working with Hadoop under Eclipse" page here : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment

I have done following things :

1. Checking out code using git command from command line
2. Run following commands :

   > mvn install -DskipTests
   >
   > mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true
3. Import project into eclipse :

   a. File -> Import -> Existing Maven project

   b. selected hadoop-common folder as a root folder.

After following above 3 steps I got "No marketplace entries found to handle Execution compile-protoc" error.

So I
1. Removed projects from eclipse

2. Executed "mvn eclipse:clean" command
3. Again imported projects into eclipse

but again I am following same errors.

Does anyone know why this error is coming? and how to resolve this error?